# Prevent page layout from inheriting default.xml?

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, xml

I have a `<link>` tag in the `<head>` section of my `default.xml` file, and I'd like to prevent that particular tag from rendering on the checkout page.

Is there anything I can add to `checkout_index_index.xml` that would **prevent this tag from being rendered?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove some block or container in magento 2 you can use **remove** attribute

example for block:`<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>`

for more details regarding xml layout instructions: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html

To remove some link from head you can use remove instruction in custom xml file inside the **head** node
example:`<remove src="my-js.js"/>`

Comment: Oh, awesome-- I knew about using the remove attribute for blocks, but didn't know I could use it for src. Thanks so much!

Comment: welcome @Brock, please mark my answer like accepted if it was helpful for your situation

Comment: There you go @JohnnySk -- tried to upvote but I don't quite have the reputation for that yet, first time learning how to mark an answer as correct. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

To remove some block or container in checkout page Magento 2. you can use **remove** attribute from the file checkout_index_index.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="block_name" remove="true"/>
<referenceConatiner name="container_name" remove="true"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, knew about that, but I didn't know about `<remove src="">`. Thanks for answering, though!